# Is it possible to implement remote controllers with Bluetooth BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, buying

I have been thinking of making bluetooth remote controllers with bluetooth low energy modules that can act as broadcasters and observers (and "peripheral" for set up)

How good would that design be (and if so would it be easy to find such components ?)
Thanks

Comment: Thomas, in its current form, your post looks a lot like a pure shopping question, which is off-topic in EE.SE. Please read [this help page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to check what kinds of questions are accepted here. Then edit your question to make it on-topic before folks close it (it's got 3 close votes already).

Comment: sorry @Ricardo I new it was border line. How should I reformulate it ? focus more on right google search terms ? ...

Comment: @Ricardo I have changed the question but now answers might not answer my original one :) more seriously where would be a good place to ask such buying questions ?

Comment: The question has been improved, but the title needs fixing as well. Normally the site accepts electronics design questions very well, and usually one can rephrase hir or her question as such by taking a step back and describing the requirements and the problem one is trying to solve. Then, as a consequence, folks may include links to products that fulfill the needs. I think that's the best you can do here.

Comment: @Ricardo I could do better indeed, thanks for the suggestion